# Using "auto" to set a literal number as "INT_PTR"

Tags: visual-c++, auto

Example:

```
void CAssignSelectedColumnDlg::SaveActionListToRegistry()
{
    const auto iSize = m_aryPtrActionColumnData.GetSize();
    for (INT_PTR i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

If I use `auto i` it will make an `int` instead of a `INT_PTR`. (`GetSize(0)` returns an `INT_PTR`). It is possible to somehow specify the value (`0`) is meant to be a `INT_PTR` without specifying the variable type? Does that make sense?

Eg: `for(auto i = 0ip ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

> INT_PTR
>
> A signed integer type for pointer precision. Use when casting a pointer to an integer to perform pointer arithmetic.
>
> This type is declared in BaseTsd.h as follows:

```
#if defined(_WIN64) 
  typedef __int64 INT_PTR; 
#else 
  typedef int INT_PTR;
#endif
```

Are you writing for one specific configuration? Then you can use [Integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

If you are building for both 32- and 64-bit configurations, I am afraid you need to specify a type as `INT_PTR`.

Alternatively, you can use [User-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

**UPDATE:**

This works for me (in case you haven't got it yet):

```
#include <Windows.h>
INT_PTR operator "" _ip(unsigned long long x) {
    return static_cast<INT_PTR>(x);
}

int main() {
    auto x = 1_ip;
}
```

Comment: I am compiling for both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle please see my updated answer.